# 2D plot overlapping circles and evolving through time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a project concerning the Velib distribution in Paris. For those who dont know Velib is a project where you can rent a bike at a station. There are about 2000 (the real value is lR0) stations all over Paris. Unfortunately sometimes there aren't any Velib to rent or any places to put your Velib so its quite annoying. I want to illustrate this problem.

To do so I have calculated the average occupation percentage `Bary_taux` in a circle of `R/2` diameter. If `Bary_taux < T` I would like to make a circle on a map (red) (I have the longitude and latitude of the center of the circle and I have about 100 values of `T_moy` all over paris) that is linked to at a time `t`.

Where it gets complicated is that I have these 100 values at 192 given times (every 10 min - 24 h) and i would like to make a plot that can evolve through time showing the evolution of the red circles.

At one give time `t`, I can draw it but i don't know how to make evolve as the time changes.

Additionally, I would like to make the red color stronger as the number of overlapping circles increases.

this is my `Bary_taux` function:

```
def Bary_taux(lng_0,lat_0,R):
    T_Bary=0
    C=0

    for k in range(lR0):
        if (((R_0[k]['position']['lng'])-lng_0)**2)+(((R_0[k['position']['lat'])-lat_0)**2)<R**2:
            C+=1
            T_bary+=Taux(k)

    return (lng_0,lat_0,R,T_bary/C)
```

and `B` is a list of the `Bary_taux` at a give time t. I have 192 `B` lists each containing 100 `Bary_taux`. This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for k in range (100):
    if B[k]<T:

        circle1 = plt.Circle((, 0), R, color='r')


fig, ax = plt.subplots() 


plt.show()
```

How can i do that ? thanks for your time.

Comment: Have a look at [plotly's animation features](https://plot.ly/python/animations/).

Answer (score 2):

In order to animate a plot in matplotlib, you can use `matplotlib.animate.FuncAnimation`. This will need a function to call for each frame. 
If we previously create all 100 circles we can use this update function to set them visible depending on some parameter.
I'm not sure if I understood your `bary_taux` and `B` correctly. So I invented some numbers myself.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np
import datetime



x = np.random.randint(0,180, size=100) # xcoordinate
y = np.random.randint(0,100, size=100) # ycoordinate
R = np.random.randint(3,10, size=100)  # radius
b = np.random.rand(192,100) # parameter by which to judge if circle is drawn or not

# set up plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0,180])
ax.set_ylim([0,100])
ax.set_aspect("equal")
text = ax.text(0.5,1.02, "", transform=ax.transAxes, ha="right" )

#create 100 circles
circles = []
for i in range(100):
    c = matplotlib.patches.Circle((x[i],y[i]), radius=R[i], color="r", alpha=0.6)
    circles.append(c)
    # add them already to the plot
    ax.add_artist(c)

def totime(t):
    minutes = datetime.timedelta(seconds=t*10*60 )
    d = datetime.datetime(1,1,1) + minutes
    return "{}h{:2d}".format(d.hour, d.minute)

def update(t):
    text.set_text(totime(t))
    for i in range(100):
        # depending on condition set circle visible or not
        if b[t,i] > 0.6:
            circles[i].set_visible(True)
        else:
            circles[i].set_visible(False)
    # redraw the canvas
    fig.canvas.draw()

# call for single plot
update(92)  
#call for animation
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=300, frames=192)


plt.show()
```